# Possible Causes for a Large Number of Sleeping Connections to a MySQL Server?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, connection

What are possible causes for a large number of sleeping connections to a MySQL Server? I'm using CodeIgniter with persistent connections disabled.

Answer (score 2):

Even though the app doesn't keep the connection open, the OS lets it hang around. See http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2006/11/12/are-php-persistent-connections-evil/

Answer (score 0):

could be a timeout issue

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't code igniter use a connection pool by default? If so, it will grab a bunch and hang on to them till it needs them.